# reading multiple lines of input always runs an infinite loop unless I print each line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I'm trying to process multiple lines of input from the console using a Scanner in Java, and it runs in an infinite loop unless I print out each line. For some reason the next line is not 'consumed' unless I print it. I don't want to print it, I only want to add each line to an array to process later, so I don't know how to 'consume' each line w/o printing it. Both of these loops are infinite:

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        commands.add(line);
        //System.out.println(line);
        sc.nextLine();
}


while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        commands.add(line);
        //System.out.println(line);
        //sc.nextLine();
    }
```

EDIT:
My scanner initialization is below, and I also edited the condition to hasNextLine(), still running an infinite loop. That print statement that prints "done" never excecutes.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        commands.add(line);
        //System.out.println(line);
        //sc.nextLine();
    }
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Could not replicate the issue. nextLine() will 'consume' the line, progressing to the next line.

Comment: Are you reading from `System.in`? Also, use `sc.hasNextLine()`!

Comment: Could you show the initialization for the Scanner sc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `hasNextLine()`, not `hasNext()`.

Printing has nothing to do with it. Printing doesn't terminate loops.

**EDIT** If you are never seeing your final `"done"`, this isn't an infinite loop at all, it is a *block*: you're never sending an end of stream to `System.in`. Type Ctrl/d or Ctrl/z depending on Windows vs. Unix/Linux/... and again, printing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Hmmm. I previously used hasNextLine(), and it was still running an infinite loop. Outside of my while loop, I put a print statement to print "done" when the loop exited, but "done" never prints, so I know that the loop never executes.

Comment: gotcha. fixed the issue using ctrl + z. Is there a way to for the loop to just stop automatically without using the end of stream commands? It seems like just a bandaid to the issue.